# How does Spring resolve views?

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc

I've been having a little trouble with View Resolution under Spring 2.5.5. Basically I'm just trying to show my view with a message from the controller passed in. The issue comes when the Controller returns the ModelAndView but the DispatcherServelt says it can't find a Handler.

All the files seem to be in the correct place. I think the issue is that Spring can't resolve the view. From what I've seen I'm using the InternalResourceResolver correctly. I'm just at a loss as to why it is failing.

Once I've made a request this is whats in the catalina.out log:

```
Feb 8, 2010 3:27:24 PM com.madebymn.newsExample.web.IndexController handleRequest
INFO: Handling a Request: /index.jsp
Feb 8, 2010 3:27:24 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/newsExample/WEB-INF/jsp/index.jsp] in DispatcherServlet with name 'catchAll'
```

Here's my web.xml:

```
<web-app version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

<display-name>A News Example</display-name>

<description>A News Example</description>

<context-param>
    <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/classes/log4j.properties</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext-jdbc.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>catchAll</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>catchAll</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>jsp/index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

Here's the Servlet XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">
<bean name="indexController" class="com.madebymn.newsExample.web.IndexController" />
<bean name="authorController" class="com.madebymn.newsExample.web.AuthorController">
    <constructor-arg>
        <ref bean="authorService" />
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>

<bean id="urlMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
    <property name="mappings">
        <props>
            <prop key="/index.jsp">indexController</prop>
            <prop key="/author/*">authorController</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>

</beans>
```

And here's my IndexController Class:

```
public class IndexController implements org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.Controller
{
    protected final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());

    @Override
    public ModelAndView handleRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        logger.info("Handling a Request: " + request.getServletPath());

        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("index");
        modelAndView.addObject("message", "someMessage");

        return modelAndView;
    }
}
```

Comment: All of your files are under `/WEB-INF/jsp` ? Thats where you are looking for all the jsp's in viewResolver.

Comment: You ask to redirect the calls to JSP pages to DispatcherServlet. Then when you get index.jsp, you're redirected to indexController. Then indexController redirects you to /newsExample/WEB-INF/jsp/index.jsp. And here again, this is redirected to DispatcherServlet. 

Something is wrong here!!! :)

Comment: What was the URL of the request you're making that errors out?

Comment: The url is http://localhost:8080/newsExample/index.jsp

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you mapped your `DispatcherServlet` as `*.jsp`, when views are JSPs too. Try to map `DispatcherServlet` to something different, like `*.html`

Comment: Thanks for that. It seems to work now. Just to clarify, whats the root of the problem? I'm not quite sure why the view doesn't get resolved when the Dispatcher is set to *.jsp.

Comment: @Matt-LLoyd: `InterlalResourceViewResolver` forwards request to the specifed view (`/WEB-INF/jsp/index.jsp`), but  `DispatcherServlet` catches this forwarded request again (because it's `*.jsp`) and tries to find a controller for it

Comment: Thanks again. That explains it all.